# Нужно привязать клавишу клавиатуры к button с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Пишу javascript приложение, нужно каждую клавишу компьютера привязать к определенной кнопке. Хочу создать на подобие драмм-машины.

вот html код:

```
<div class="dramm-mashine-box__top">
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-1">1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-2">2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-3">3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-4">4</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-5">5</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-6">6</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-7">7</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-8">8</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-9">9</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-0">0</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Может клавишу клавиатуры вы хотите привязать

Comment: Именно так. Может я оговорился? Ну именно, мне нужно привязать к клавише клавиатуры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По фану написал себе это.

```js
const arr = []
let sum = 0
const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key')
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition))
window.addEventListener('keydown', playSound)


function playSound(e) {
  const attr = `[data-key="${e.key}"]`
  const audio = document.querySelector('audio' + attr)
  const key = document.querySelector('div' + attr)
  
  if (!key)
    return
  
  key.classList.add('playing')
  audio.currentTime = 0
  audio.play()

  arr.push(event.key)
  document.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = arr.join(', ')
  document.querySelector('.sum').innerHTML = sum += +event.key
}

function removeTransition(e) {
  if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return
  this.classList.remove('playing')
}
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.output {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px
}

.output-sum {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px
}

.keys {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.key {
  border: .4rem solid black;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  transition: all .07s ease;
  width: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  text-shadow: 0 0 .5rem black;
}

.playing {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border-color: #ffc600;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #ffc600;
}

kbd {
  display: block;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.sound {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  color: #ffc600;
}
```

```html
<div class="output">Нажмите цифру</div>
    <div class="output-sum">Сумма цифр: <sapn class="sum">0</span></div>
    
    <div class="keys">
      <div data-key="1" class="key">
        <kbd>1</kbd>
        <span class="sound">clap</span>
      </div>
    <div data-key="2" class="key">
        <kbd>2</kbd>
        <span class="sound">hihat</span>
      </div>
    <div data-key="3" class="key">
        <kbd>3</kbd>
        <span class="sound">kick</span>
      </div>
       <div data-key="4" class="key">
        <kbd>4</kbd>
        <span class="sound">openhat</span>
      </div>
      <div data-key="5" class="key">
        <kbd>5</kbd>
        <span class="sound">boom</span>
      </div>
      <div data-key="6" class="key">
        <kbd>6</kbd>
        <span class="sound">ride</span>
      </div>
      <div data-key="7" class="key">
        <kbd>7</kbd>
        <span class="sound">snare</span>
      </div>
      <div data-key="8" class="key">
        <kbd>8</kbd>
        <span class="sound">tom</span>
      </div>
      <div data-key="9" class="key">
        <kbd>9</kbd>
        <span class="sound">tink</span>
      </div>
      <div data-key="0" class="key">
        <kbd>0</kbd>
        <span class="sound">clap</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <audio data-key="1" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/CP.mp3"></audio>
    <audio data-key="2" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/OH25.mp3"></audio>
    <audio data-key="3" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/SD0025.mp3"></audio>
    <audio data-key="4" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/CY0010.mp3"></audio>
    <audio data-key="5" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/CP.mp3"></audio>
    <audio data-key="6" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/CH.mp3"></audio>
    <audio data-key="7" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/SD0010.mp3"></audio>
    <audio data-key="8" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/OH25.mp3"></audio>
    <audio data-key="9" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/CB.mp3"></audio>
    <audio data-key="0" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/CP.mp3"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// создадим коллецию клавиша > кнопка
const $buttons = $('.dramm-mashine-box__top button');
const keyMap = new Map();
$buttons.each((i, btn) => {
  // либо через id получать код к которому должна кнопка подключаться
  // либо через data-attribute
  keyMap.set(btn.innerHTML, btn);
});

function handleButtonPress() {
  // делаем с кнопкой что хотим
  // кнопка доступна по this
  $(this).addClass('pressed');
}

function handleButtonUnPress() {
  $(this).removeClass('pressed');
}

$(document).on('keypress', function (event) {
  const code = event.key;
  const button = keyMap.get(code);
  if(button) handleButtonPress.call(button);
});


$(document).on('keyup', function (event) {
  const code = event.key;
  const button = keyMap.get(code);
  if(button) handleButtonUnPress.call(button);
});
```

```css
button.pressed {
   outline: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dramm-mashine-box__top">
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-1">1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-2">2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-3">3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-4">4</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-5">5</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-6">6</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-7">7</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-8">8</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-9">9</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-0">0</button>
</div>
```